# What is the iOS keyboard lifecycle?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Im using a bespoke architecture for an app which uses react-native and Unity.

The library lives here: https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-unity-view

The problem I am facing is that the keyboard will not show on iOS when i select a text input on Unity.

But if i was to open a text input within the react-native side. The keyboard functionality will then work on the unity side, and continue to work for the 'session'.
But no keyboard will show unless i first 'trigger' a keyboard to open on the react-native side.

If i log within Unity side, it thinks that the keyboard is actually open and visible.

My guess is that its some sort of lifecycle event which is initialing the keyboard, and react-native is calling this. But it doesn't get called by unity when setup this way.

What would be the lifecycle for iOS? Can it be triggered manually which will then 'enable' the keyboard?

Thank you

Comment: This package is no longer maintained, try using this one: https://github.com/wowmaking/react-native-unity

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at this, but there is a fork of the original which is being maintained and I could apply a fix myself if I can understand the problem more.